# Alternative to indexing a MySQL view

Tags: mysql, view

the deal is this:

I have a MySQL database that is built in this manner:
There are three tables, one for "objects":

```
ID | Type       | Name        | Description
--------------------------------------------
1  | Restaurant | Joe's Grill | A Great Place
```

and than a table for metadata about each "object" designed like:

```
Object ID | Name ID | Description ID
-----------------------------------
1         | 2       | 4
```

and another table for the strings of the metadata:

```
ID | String
---------------
1  | Hello
2  | City
3  | London
4  | Paris
```

so in this case Joe's Grill restaurant (ID: 1) has a metadata attached to it
(you can see that by the Object ID column of the metadata table)
and the Name ID and Description ID columns correspond to the strings of the metadata strings table.

The problem is that SELECT queries will need multiple JOINs each time,
so I wanted to create a view that will do this automatically,
the thing is I also want indexes for this view because the view will
also get very large.

The question is:

1. I know it's not possible to create an index for a view? is there an alternative to this?
2. if not, what's the next best option? maybe there's another way except a view
   to create a table out of a query?
   maybe set up a script that will do this?
3. if neither of those is possible, is there anything else I can do?

Thank you all in advance, I've really been cracking my head over this
for quite some time.

Comment: A view is basically just a stored query. Any query involving the view will involve the indexes on the underlying table. Unless the view contains derived fields (e.g. "select concat(a, b) from..."), there wouldn't be any point in indexing the view's fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you want a materialized view.

1. you can update the mv with triggers
2. you can update the view in a batch
3. there is a tool called flexviews
4. or you can update the materialized view in your code.

an alternative is to just generate large but well optimized queries. that might be okay depending upon your requirements...

Comment: Thanks a lot, all the options are worth considering :), only option 2 doesn't sound like it'll help me because it's still creating a view and I can't index a view.

Comment: i just meant creating the materialized view in a batch. just wipe it out and recreate it every so often. you can use the rename table command to do it atomically.

Answer (score 2):

This model is an Entity-Attribute-Value model or EAV.  It allows for a schema-less schema.  As such, it is difficult to see how a view or table can track this, since new attributes need new columns and the relatively static nature of a data schema means that the view or table would need to be recreated.

When someone takes object 1 with a new name/value, you would have to add a column to the view or table.

This kind of defeats the dynamic nature of the EAV model.

I think you should ask yourself why these metadata items are put into EAV if you want them to be treated more like traditional attributes (which is what your approach to using a view implies).

As far as indexing, if you make your IDs primary keys and index them, you'll probably be fine.  In SQL Server, I'd probably make them the PK and cluster on that, too.  And probably not even have any non-clustered indexes - depending on the queries.  If you were going from right to left, i.e. finding all things tagged with a city as paris, I might index a little differently, including a non-clustered index on the text column and on the foreign keys (indexed both ways) in the entities.  That all depends on the usage patterns I would see, though.

Comment: +1 for wording it much better than the answer I was writing :).  EAV is great if you don't know what extra data you might attach to a record. But if you know what the columns are going to be, it's kind of pointless.

Comment: @Cfreak There are certainly useful views for this, but not generally ones that do pivots.  On the other hand, I have made quite powerful table-valued functions which do dynamic pivots using fancy tricks in SQL Server, but generally these techniques are best left to the tips of special use cases - I always strive use database features in increasing order of complexity.

Comment: Hi, first of all it's nice to know the name of this data structure :). Anyway as to the question why I use EAV the answer is that the view I'm looking to create is just a part of the database, there are a lot of other parts that rely on this data structure and work great with it. My main goal is to use the values of the metadata strings table (like getting all restaurants that are in paris), the engine right now is MyISAM, if I create an index on the string column of the metadata string table will it work the same as if there was an index on the "City" Column of the view?

Comment: It kind of sounds to me like a view will always be kind of inefficient because it's not actually stored and just directs to the original table.

Comment: @fiftyeight I think you should be using InnoDB, to start with.  In addition, nothing will be as fast as an appropriately indexed materialized table.  However a view on appropriately indexed normalized tables is no less performant than an ordinary inline query over those same tables.  You may want to look at flexviews: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/03/23/using-flexviews-part-one-introduction-to-materialized-views/

Answer (score 0):

I'd be questioning your database design here, a query with 3 tables isn't that complex or costly to run.  Show us an example of what your query looks like, it sounds as though you're trying to do something that a better design might cater for